# 2nd-order backward difference approximation for temporal terms of Euler–Bernoulli beam

Tags: finite-difference, numerics, simulation, stability, implicit-methods

I am trying to solve the Euler–Bernoulli beam numerically in structural dynamics analysis:
$$\frac{\partial^2w(x,t)}{\partial t^2}= \frac {q(x,t)}{\mu(x)}-\frac {1}{\mu(x)}\frac {\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left[E(x)I(x)\frac {\partial^2w(x,t)}{\partial x^2}\right]-\beta(x) \frac {\partial w(x,t)}{\partial t}$$
I use backward difference approximation for the temporal terms and central difference approximation for spatial terms. The backward difference approximations for the temporal terms referenced to [this](https://www.dam.brown.edu/people/alcyew/handouts/numdiff.pdf):
$$\frac{\partial^2w(x_i,t_{j+1})}{\partial t^2} = \frac{2w(x_i,t_{j+1})-5w(x_i,t_j)+4w(x_i,t_{j-1})-w(x_i,t_{j-2})}{\Delta t^3}$$
$$\frac{\partial w(x_i,t_{j+1})}{\partial t} = \frac{3w(x_i,t_{j+1})-4w(x_i,t_j)+w(x_i,t_{j-1})}{2\Delta t}$$
The discretion for spatial terms is skipped here, and the term $\frac {q(x,t)}{\mu(x)}$ will be $\frac {q(x_i,t_{j+1})}{\mu(x)}$. Sort out those terms and organize them as $Ax=B$ and I simply write them in this form:
$$[A][w(t_{j+1})]=[B(t_j,t_{j-1},t_{j-2},q(t_{j+1}))]$$
where *A* is the matrix of coefficients, $w(t_{j+1})$ is the vector of $w$ at $j+1$ time step along the beam, and $B$ is the vector of the combination of some known values and unknown values.

My question is: **the RHS of this system has $q(x_i,t_{j+1})$ which are values that come from the next time step, and it is not known at the current time step**, therefore, how to deal with these unknown values when solving this equation of system? I am wondering whether the **predictor-corrector** method can deal with this problem, or if another method will be more suitable.

Additional information: I am doing structural dynamics simulation, so the load is calculated from another part of the code every time step, so I cannot know the next time step's load in advance. And using backward differences for temporal terms because of the stability consideration.

Comment: This is an implicit method, meaning you have to solve a linear system to obtain the values at the current time step. To start the iteration, use an explicit method with high order of accuracy.

Comment: @whpowell96, thanks a lot, but I am still confused, what's the meaning of "To start the iteration, use an explicit method with high order of accuracy.", if I start the iteration with the explicit method, how to shift to an implicit method?

Comment: Use an explicit method to compute the first three solution values then use this method to compute all later values.

Comment: @whpowell96, thanks, it seems that your comment is to address the initializing of the implicit method. But my problem is how to deal with the unknown values 'q(j+1)' of the next time step in RHS of the linear system.

Comment: How is $q$ not known here? Usually $q$ refers to prescribed load. If $q$ depends on $w$ somehow so it is not known, then you have to solve an implicit equation for $w(t_{j+1})$

Comment: @whpowell96, when discretizing second-order derivation temporal term at $j+1$th time step of beam equation, $q(x,t)$ need to have at the same time step $q(x_i,t_{j+1})$, right? or maybe I understand this discretization worng.

Comment: Yes that is true. But why don't we know $q(x_i, t_{j+1})$? Does $q$ depend on the solution $u$? Usually $q$ is given

Comment: @whpowell96 No, $q$ does not depend on the solution $u$, $q$ comes from another part of the code which runs with beam calculation code at the same time.